# What is the difference between link rate and pixel rate in Display Port?

Tags: bit-rate, displayport

I was going through the Display Port Specification. I came across the below para:

"1.7.1 Make-up of the Main Link
The Main Link consists of one, two or four AC-coupled, doubly terminated differential pairs (called lanes).
AC-coupling facilitates the silicon process migration since the DisplayPort transmitter and receiver may have
different common mode voltages.
Three link rates are supported, 5.4Gbps, 2.7Gbps and 1.62Gbps per lane. All enabled lanes must be operating
at the same link rate. The link rate is decoupled from the pixel rate. The pixel rate is regenerated from the link
symbol clock using the time stamp values M and N. The capabilities of the DisplayPort transmitter and
receiver, and the quality of the channel (or a cable) will determine whether the link rate is set to 5.4Gbps,
2.7Gbps or 1.62Gbps per lan"

What is the difference between pixel rate and link rate?
My understanding is that the display port transfers pixel as  part of the other information like HFP, HBP, etc. How then can the rate be different?

Answer (score 3):

It's no different than having a gigabit ethernet link between devices, and sending only the data packets you really need at some slower rate, like at kilobit per second.

In some other display interfaces, the pixel clock is used for the link clock to transmit pixel data over the link. It also means that for each or any possible pixel clock rate, you must support many different link clock rates.

But in DisplayPort, there are only few fixed link rates available, and the pixels are sent in packets, along with timing info how to regenerate that pixel clock in the receiving end.

Answer (score 0):

Link rate is expressed in Gigabits per second.
Pixel rate is expressed in Megahertz or Mega Pixels per second.
There is a simple formula for calculating Pixel rate for a given resolution of a video:

Horizontal Total * Vertical Total * Frame Rate (or Vertical frequency).

On the VESA website, these are available under the free standards download section.